# Despite correct OG tags, facebook sharing uses incorrect image?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I have correct OG tags in the meta tags of my page, the facebook OG tags debugger shows the correct content and has no errors or warnings, but actual shares use an image that is seemingly picked at random.

Bizarrely the text is updating correctly, if I change the OG title, or OG description, they update immediately.

Is there some cache that needs clearing or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re-scraping the URL via the debug tool or via API will clear the FB cache. (But only if there are no errors.)

Comment: I have already re-scraped it, the debug tool says everything is fine and the preview it shows is correct, but it's not showing the same content as the preview in an actual share.

Comment: Then give us the URL of an actual example where we can see the problem.

Comment: http://milupa.de/blubbern-1

Comment: you are missing some double quotes in the code. line 59 and 329.

Comment: That shows the same image in debug tool preview, and when I try to actually share it on Facebook. If it doesn’t for you, then it is likely rather a local cache issue. Try a different browser/device.

Comment: what CBroe said. also, you should use an image that fits the specifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: The image fits facebook and whatsapp specs, @CBroe which image do you see?

Comment: The one specified in the meta tag, https://www.milupa.de/media/2075/pillar-1_8_355x200.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=200&height=200&rnd=131239613510000000

Comment: Wierd, thanks for the confirmation!